# How to fixed Highcharts data area with scrollbar?

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, highcharts

Task include Sleep,Family time,Eat and Work

When I move the scrollbar , data area will change over time

How can I fixed data area when I move the scrollbar(always show 4 tasks) ?

Or

How can I hide the lines when the task is no data?

thank you

Comment: the sample: http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/1573/

Comment: Scrollbar is basend on series, so when your task "take time" from 00:00 to 6:00, how it should be displayed at 12.00 ?

Comment: Task of eat at 20:30-21:00 .
When I move the scrollbar the front ,task of eat should be hidden.
Task of Sleep at 00:00-06:00.
When I move the scrollbar the Behind,task of Sleep will be hidden.
How to make highcharts normal display?
other sample :http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/1577/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set min/max parameter http://jsfiddle.net/r6emu/1579/

```
min:0,
max:3
```